# How can I determine transmission model?

Tags: automatic-transmission, mazda

I'm in the market for a shift solenoid C for a Mazda 323, year 2000 (Lantis), automatic transmission.

The listings I've found online sell solenoids which are listed as compatible with all Mazda transmissions **FN4A-EL**, models **99-UP**.

How can I determine the exact transmission model in my car?

**EDIT:** I don't mean to derail the question, but the reason I ask is because I'm looking for a replacement solenoid due to a P0763 error. Mechanic recommended replacing the transmission, but other threads I found said replacing the transmission due to a faulty solenoid is going about it wrong. So I'm considering my options - replace solenoid vs. replace transmission.

Comment: There should be an ID tag on the [top of the transmission](https://catalog.americantransmission.com/TRANScart/images/big/fn4a-el.png).

Comment: I'm rather new at this - would the tag be accessible/visible without disassembling anything? Where is the transmission located?

Comment: That's what I'm assuming. It looks as though it should be visible inside the engine compartment from above. Look for which side the transmission is attached to the engine (away from the alternator and serpentine belt). Then look for the tag. If you place yourself just behind the transmission, it should be on the right hand side of it. There may be some intake ducting in the way, but it should be fairly easy to see around or to move stuff out of the way to find it. You may need to clean it off as they'll get grime on them.

Comment: You could also call a dealer with the VIN and they'd be able to tell you.

Comment: I finally got around to looking for the tag - I did find a big metallic tag which I think is the ID tag, but I'm not sure because it looks different (much more old fashioned) than most of the ID tags on Google Images. Also, I can't find any mention of the letters/numbers on Google. [Looks like this](http://i.imgur.com/HiA1Q4b.jpg) (the yellow text is what I _think_ it says, also I'm not sure if maybe `6` is `G`, and the first `O` may just be the piece holding the tag in place). Edited my first post to make things clear.